Замена изображения на ссылку на изображение
есть несколько изображений на странице типа


<img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/qwert.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/werty.jpg" alt="" />



как на JQuery поменять эти изображения на ссылки на эти изображения и добавить к каждому изображению описание alt как показано ниже


<a href="https://images4.imagebam.com/qwert.jpg"><img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/qwert.jpg" alt="image1" /></a>
<a href="https://images4.imagebam.com/werty.jpg"><img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/werty.jpg" alt="image2" /></a>




Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
